# Hover Over Stopped Working in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am just learning coding and cannot figure out this problem. I had the color set for `hover` and then somehow, it disappeared and now I cannot get it back. check my code below:

```
/* the styles for the aside */
#aside1 {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    height: 350px;
    }
#nav_list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    }
#nav_list ul li {
    align-content: left;
    width: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border: 2px solid black; 
}
#nav_list ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: orange
}
#nav_list ul li a:hover, a:focus { color: green }
```

Comment: Please also show the HTML that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the way you have written the last line, bear in mind that since your using vanilla css, to target the :focus pseduo class you need to specify a selector.

It should be like this:

```
#nav_list ul li a:hover, #nav_list ul li a:focus { color: green }
```

This should definitely work provided your html hasnt changed.

Comment: Is it the hover or the focus that isn't working?

Comment: Thank you, rhysclay! This worked like a charm!